# How to enable autocompletion for globally registered Vue components in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2

The autocompletion feature of VSCode works perfectly fine with local registration of Vue components, like so:

```js
<template>
  <base-button />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import BaseButton from '@/components/base/BaseButton.vue';

@Component({
  components: { BaseButton }
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Then, for example, with my `base-button` which has the props `extraClass`, `id`, and `type`, VSCode shows me all of them properly:

[image: Screenshot: autocompletion of VSCode]

But when I register my `base` components globally in `main.ts`, like so:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

import BaseButton from '@/components/base/BaseButton.vue';
Vue.component('BaseButton', BaseButton);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Vue still works as expected but VSCode now won't show me any autocompletions for those components.

How can I change that?
How can I enable VSCode to show me the autocompletion for the props of my self-written components when I register them globally?

Comment: @AluanHaddad where should I add that?

Comment: I misunderstood what that calling `Vue.component` does. Disregard